# Forums to discuss and learn hot topics of economics research

Tags: research

Math Overflow is the best forum to learn about pure math researches. Does there exist a similar website or forum for economics researches?

The econ stack exchange seems quiet.

Comment: At least we are better than the alpha-male dominated https://www.econjobrumors.com/ :) On a serious note, follow people on twitter, subscribe to [NEP](http://nep.repec.org/), and maybe use [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Economics/).